# GitHub Desktop Stuck on Pushing To Origin

Tags: github, github-desktop

When I tried to push to remote repository using GitHub Desktop Application, it stuck on Pushing to origin.

[image]

How to solve this? I tried reinstall but that does not fix the issue.

Comment: did you work it out?

Comment: is the repo on Https ?

Answer (score 0):

check if you have saved all the changes that you made recently or not.
for that type `git add.` (Dot is mandatory)
after adding commit the changes `git commit`
now all changes have came to staging area, now you can push the files..
Hope it helps you...
correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Problem is with GitHub desktop, Git bash works fine.